# Python inverted index issue: "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, indexing, unpack

i'm trying to build an inverted index, but i continue to get the same error

ValueError: too many values to unpack

It occurs in this part of my code:

```
def inverted_index(self, text):

    terms = self.getTerms(text)
    inverted = {}
    for index, word in terms:
            locations = inverted.setdefault(word)
            locations.append(index)

    return inverted
```

to be more specific in the line "for inde, word in terms:"

if i print terms i get a list of words:

```
['12th', 'comput', 'olympiad', 'ciao', 'chiamo', 'alberto', 'lancellotti', 'scrivendo', 'primo', 'articolo', 'piccolo', 'motor', 'ricerca', 'manual']
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for index, word in enumerate(terms)
```

`enumerate` will give you the index of each item in the list

```
In [5]: for index, word in enumerate(terms):              
            print(index,word)       
(0, '12th')
(1, 'comput')
(2, 'olympiad')
(3, 'ciao')
(4, 'chiamo')
(5, 'alberto')
(6, 'lancellotti')
(7, 'scrivendo')
(8, 'primo')
(9, 'articolo')
(10, 'piccolo')
(11, 'motor')
(12, 'ricerca')
(13, 'manual')
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is complaining because each iteration of `terms` only returns one thing - the value. What you want is

```
for index, word in enumerate(terms):
```

That will return both the index for the item and the item itself.